# Python Installing issu

Tags: python, installation

[image]

I reinstalled it many times but nothing is solved , what should I do ?

Comment: Don't know that language. But have you tried Anaconda? https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: This question is useless to future readers, even in the unlikely event that the image link survives.  Please read "[ask]", and the links at the bottom of that page.

Comment: try to install in English language

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is a little old, I have a possible solution.

In English the message is:

> Unable to start the program because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll cannot be found on your computer. Try to reinstall the program to fix this problem.

The problem is a little confusing because it's not really a python problem. It's a DLL that you need to re-install.

Simply put you don't have the api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll on your machine, or it is unregistered. You could try to re-register it, but it's easier just to do the following:

1. Run windows update.
2. Download Visual C++ Redistributeable: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2977003
3. Run the installer and select "uninstall".
4. Run the installer again and select "install".

If Anaconda already fixed it for you, I hope this still helps someone somewhere sometime.